# Explanation on this haskell code which takes a list of uncurried elements and curries them

Tags: haskell, currying

I am trying to analyze this haskell code, if anyone familiar w/ haskell could provide some insight on what is going on with this code, I would greatly appreciate it.

`curryList :: ([a] -> d) -> (a -> [a] -> d)`

`curryList unCurried = curry $ uncurry (\x y -> unCurried (x : y))`

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with currying. A function of type `[a] -> d` is trivially curried.

Comment: Uncurrying `\x y -> unCurried (x : y)` produces `\(x, y) -> unCurried (x:y)`; currying that gets you `\x y -> unCurried (x:y)` again. `unCurried` is a confusing name for the argument, because it's being applied to a single argument of type `[a]`, not a tuple.

Comment: Perhaps you are supposed to define `curryList` in terms of `uncurry (:) :: (x, [x]) -> [x]`?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it would be easier to understand if you remove `curry . uncurry`?

```
curryList f x xs = f (x : xs)
```

```
curryList sum 10 [1, 2, 3]
> 16
```

Comment: This is a textbook question's answer which requires it to use curry and uncurry, while you've provided a much more simple and easier to understand solution. I am curious as to what this textbook solution is doing.

Comment: @ddd It's not "really" using `curry` and `uncurry` though; they don't do anything interesting or significant. The code in the question simply makes a 2-argument function `\x y -> unCurried (x : y)`, then it uncurries it but immediately curries it again, so it ends up exactly as it was. Any 2-argument function can have `curry . uncurry` wrapped around it so that it "uses" `curry` and `uncurry`, but that's no more interesting than taking an arithmetic expression `x` and changing it to `x + 1 - 1` so that it "uses addition".

Comment: @ddd It seems weird that that would be an *answer* to a textbook question. I can see it being the question itself, where the exercise is for you to *notice* that it ends up exactly the same by working through the definitions of `curry` and `uncurry`?

Answer (score 1):

If you were to insist to use `curry` and `uncurry`, then what I'd suggest you do is to uncurry the `:` operator and proceed from there.

```
uncurry (:) :: (a,[a]) -> [a]
```

This can be composed with the `unCurried :: [a] -> d` function:

```
unCurried . uncurry (:) :: (a,[a]) -> d
```

...and by again currying that whole thing you get the desired final result

```
curry $ unCurried . uncurry (:) :: a -> [a] -> d
```

So, as a whole function:

```
curryList unCurried = curry $ unCurried . uncurry (:)
```

Which is still worse than simply `curryList unCurried x xs = unCurried (x:xs)`, but at least the use of `curry` and `uncurry` serves some purpose there, namely that you can compose the functions simply with `.` because there's only one (tuple) argument.

Comment: I am still relatively new to Haskell so looking at your code, could you explain what this line of code is doing `curryList unCurried = curry $ unCurried . uncurry (:)`. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I already explained it much detail, don't see what more could be added. If you still don't understand it, experiment around with GHCi (particularly `:t`).